# How to create a spinner animation that displays on button press in JS?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to add a spinner to my website but I am struggling to get it to work and could do with some help. I'm trying to make it so the js.p5 canvas is on top of the video but is hidden until the play button is pressed in which the spinner animation plays until the page is refreshed (the spinner does not have to be an actual spinner for a video its purely for homework reasons to demonstrate what I've learned in class. Having the spinner play on top of the video area when the button is pressed will suffice).

My through process was that the event listener would execute the code in the 'spinner' function which would then create the spinner. I know that the event listener registers the users input with the button, and the 'drawCanvas', 'draw', and 'drawElements' functions display the spinner on the video just fine on their own but when using the event handler, it doesn't.

Thanks in advance everyone :D

```js
function play_pause() {
  var playpause = document.getElementById('playPause');
  if (playpause.innerHTML == "Play") playpause.innerHTML = "Pause";
  else playpause.innerHTML = "Play";
};

var playpause = document.getElementById('playPause')
playpause.addEventListener('click', function spinner() {
  function drawCanvas() {
    let spinCanvas = createCanvas(100, 100);
    spinCanvas.position(450, 560, 'absolute');
    spinCanvas.hide();
    frameRate (13);
  };

  function draw() {
    background(0, 0, 0, 80);
    drawElements();
  };

  function drawElements() {
    let num = 8;
    push();
    translate(width/2, height/2);
    let cir = 360/num*(frameCount%num);
    rotate(radians(cir));
    noStroke();
    fill(0, 102, 204);
    ellipse(30, 0, 22, 22);
    pop();
    stroke(255, 255, 0, 18);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's the W3schools link:
[W3Scool link to "How to make a loader"](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp)

and then you can just do:

```
function toggleSpinner(boolean){
  if(boolean == true){
    select('.loader').hide() // .style.visibility = hidden; I believe is in native
  } else if(boolean == false) {
    select('.loader').show()
  }
}
```

also you can totally just do ..if(boolean){... and ..if(!boolean){...

I don't exactly believe that it'd be all that great to do with js, though you can probably do the same in js with:

```
let interv = setInterval() and
    interv.clearInterval()
and arc() and translate() -> rotate() and stuff
```